# Is it possible to pass parameter in the cognos by SQL?

Tags: sql, plsql, cognos-10, cognos-bi, cognos-8

I am having SQL query as "select * from all_objects where owner = : owner;". Can it be possible to create prompt with this query in cognos 10.2.2.Please suggest me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a prompt macro. The SQL with the macro would look something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM all_objects WHERE owner = #sq(prompt('owner','string',''))#
```

The third parameter of the prompt() function specifies a default value. If you supply one, the prompt becomes optional.

Comment: Hi,Thank you for your response.I tried the above query but when i run report i am getting as "No Data Available".Can you please suggest me to get the data in report.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try it without the sq() function wrapping the prompt() function

Comment: Hi Johnsonium.Thank you for your suggestion but that also not fetching data in report.Again i am getting as "No Data Availabale".I think the SQL Query containing parameter will not get data in Cognos report.?

Comment: Is there any way for you to view the actual SQL that's being passed? That will probably you point you to a solution.

Comment: yes Johnsonium. There is option in tools menu as 'Show Generated SQL/MDX'.But with that query also i am getting as 'No data available'.Is there anyother ways to solve this.Please suggest me.Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I don't mean to run the query. You should inspect the query to determine why it's resulting in 'No data available'. Specifically, look at the WHERE clause to see if there's a type mismatch problem etc.

Comment: I finally got. Thank you Johnsonium.